# Compiling Delphi 2007 packages in Delphi xe3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2007

I'm trying to recompile a package (delphi2007) with Delphi XE3 and I get the error: "E2199 Packages 'vcl' and 'rtl' both contain unit ' ' "
Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: You're trying to recompile a Delphi2007 package with XE3? I don't get the idea. If you want a D2007 package, you have to compile it with D2007 since no other version will produce a compatible bpl.

Comment: Please provide the actual error message (including the unit name it's saying is in both packages). This isn't normal for units that are part of Delphi itself (it often happens when you use third-party components or your own).

Comment: Im trying recompile because we are migrating! We just need all our code works same way with XE3 like in D2007.

Comment: Ken, the error is this. No unit name was provided, only say: "E2199 Packages 'vcl' and 'rtl' both contain unit ' ' "

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the environment variable "PATH". Installing XE3 removes the path of Delphi 2007 ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Codegear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin'), it solves adding manualy to "PATH" variable, before than XE3 path

Comment: I highly doubt that it must be **before**. Once I had an `access violation` in editor caused by the PATH variable with entries of older RAD Studio placed before entries of newer RAD Studio.